Accessing Stable Diffusion img2img-pipelines latent representations with Python
I would like to blend the latent representations of two Stable Diffusion img2img-pipeline images;
I think the blending part will be a trivial task, but I have extreme difficulties accessing the latents.
There is an excellent example of txt2img blending using UNet at HuggingFace cookbooks (https://huggingface.co/learn/cookbook/stable_diffusion_interpolation), but I have not been able to find how to do something similar with img2img.
Also, I found another beautiful example using Keras (https://keras.io/examples/generative/random_walks_with_stable_diffusion/) but that is txt2img, too.
I have researched the matter to the best of my abilities and for what I understand, the goal of blending the imagebased SD latent representations could be achieved using VAE:
https://medium.com/@onkarmishra/stable-diffusion-explained-1f101284484d
https://wandb.ai/capecape/ddpm_clouds/reports/Using-Stable-Diffusion-VAE-to-encode-satellite-images--VmlldzozNDA2OTgx
However, my skills are not so good that I would understand what really happens in the processes and I haven't been able to utilize these examples.
I came up with this, though:
import numpy as np
import torch
from diffusers import StableDiffusionImg2ImgPipeline, StableDiffusionPipeline
from PIL import Image

model_name = "stabilityai/stable-diffusion-2-base"
input_pipe = StableDiffusionImg2ImgPipeline.from_pretrained(model_name, safety_checker=None).to("cuda")
output_pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(model_name, safety_checker=None).to("cuda")

init_image = Image.open("sample_image.jpg").convert("RGB")

prompt = "A Japanese wood painting"

with torch.no_grad():
    initial_image = input_pipe(prompt=prompt, # Get img2img SD image
                         image=init_image,
                         strength=0.35,
                         guidance_scale=10,
                         output_type="pil").images[0]

    # Convert PIL image to tensor and normalize to [-1, 1]
    initial_image_tensor = torch.tensor(np.array(initial_image)).permute(2, 0, 1).unsqueeze(0).float().to("cuda") / 255.0
    initial_image_tensor = (initial_image_tensor - 0.5) * 2  

    # Encode image to latent space
    latents = input_pipe.vae.encode(initial_image_tensor).latent_dist.sample() * 0.18215

    # Decode back latents to an image for visualization
    decoded_latent_tensor = input_pipe.vae.decode(latents)['sample']
    decoded_latent_tensor = (decoded_latent_tensor / 2 + 0.5).clamp(0, 1)  # Normalize to [0, 1]
    decoded_latent_numpy = decoded_latent_tensor[0].permute(1, 2, 0).cpu().numpy()
    decoded_latent_pil = Image.fromarray((decoded_latent_numpy * 255).astype(np.uint8))

    # Generate final image from latent representation
    final_image = output_pipe(prompt=prompt,
                              latents=latents,
                              num_inference_steps=50,  # Increase steps for better quality
                              guidance_scale=7.5,  # Adjust guidance scale for better prompt adherence
                              output_type="pil").images[0]

# Show the results: initial image, SD img2img, latent representation image, SD from latent
width, height = init_image.size
combined_image = Image.new('RGB', (width * 4, height))
combined_image.paste(init_image, (0, 0))
combined_image.paste(initial_image, (width, 0))
combined_image.paste(decoded_latent_pil, (width * 2, 0))
combined_image.paste(final_image, (width * 3, 0))

combined_image.show()

The images generated are like this:

The leftmost image is the initial image.
The second on the left is the SD img2img result for japanese wood painting, seems about fine.
The third is the reverse decoded image representation of the VAE encoded result, which I understand to be the latent representation of the img2img result.
The last is the result of SD txt2img pipeline of the latent representation and the prompt.
The last two pictures seem to be always the same. It looks like the process is totally deterministic for the last two images and the prompt does not seem to affect the end result at all.
What am I doing wrong? Also, it is clear that I don't understand the stable diffusion process concerning the latents. I have gone through a multitude of general descriptions of the SD process and huggingface docs, if someone could point me in the direction of good resources, that would be appreciated as well. If it is pertinent, my final goal would be blending latents of video sequence frames for better continuity.
